# Django unittests - ImproperlyConfigured error

Tags: django, testing, testcase, unittest2

Im trying to write tests for my module. When i run:

```
python manage.py test my_module
```

Im getting message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Please fill out the database NAME in the settings module before using the database.
```

I dont have any test yet, just BaseTest where im creating users, groups and assigning permissions.

Where could be the problem? Server normally works, configuration seems to be good. Do i need to define settings for test?

---

*Ok. I think i know what was the problem :] I had lists with permissions stored in other module. So i were writting `from module.perms import perms` (normal python list). Its seems, that python is doing something more than just import that list from other module to my module. And that was the cause of failing.*

**Solution:**
Surround code after list definition with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ...
```

Then everything should be working good.

Comment: Run `manage.py test -v2 my_module` and see if any extra output helps with the problem.  Django also supports a `TEST_NAME` entry for a test database name but if not specified defaults to `test_<NAME>` so this shouldn't be a problem.  You could try setting `TEST_NAME` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think i know what was the problem :] I had lists with permissions stored in other module. So i were writting from module.perms import perms (normal python list). Its seems, that python is doing something more than just import that list from other module to my module. And that was the cause of failing.

Solution: Surround code after list definition with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ...
```

Then everything should be working good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your DATABASE setting in place in settings.py, and your app needs to be in installed apps. For example:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'database.sqlite',
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm at a loss then, sorry. The error message definitely points to a settings.py problem. The only thing I can recommend is to look at [this tutorial](http://www.tdd-django-tutorial.com/) and see if anything there helps.

Comment: Yeah i know, but its strange because settings file seems to be good. Thanks for tut.

Answer (score 0):

`python manage.py test` doesn't use the `NAME` database defined in settings.py `DATABASES`. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#the-test-database) -

> Tests that require a database (namely, model tests) will not use your
>   "real" (production) database. Separate, blank databases are created
>   for the tests.
>
> Regardless of whether the tests pass or fail, the test databases are
>   destroyed when all the tests have been executed.
>
> By default the test databases get their names by prepending test_ to
>   the value of the NAME settings for the databases defined in DATABASES.
>   When using the SQLite database engine the tests will by default use an
>   in-memory database (i.e., the database will be created in memory,
>   bypassing the filesystem entirely!). If you want to use a different
>   database name, specify TEST_NAME in the dictionary for any given
>   database in DATABASES.

To answer your question. You can define a test database with the `TEST_NAME` [setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEST_NAME). But you shouldn't have to.

Comment: Problem solved. Solution in question. Thanks for help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another potential solution for people finding this through search:

I was trying to define my own `TestRunner` class inside my settings file, which meant it had to import `DjangoTestSuiteRunner`.  This import at the top of the file caused the `ImproperlyConfigured` error.  Moving the custom TestRunner class to a separate file resolved the issue.